# MemoryMappedFile not perfectly synchronized between processes?

Tags: c#, vba, memory, ipc

I'm exploring various techniques for IPC, currently: Memory Mapped Files. In short, in C# I am creating this via

```
using (var f = MemoryMappedFile.CreateOrOpen("TestMap", 10, MemoryMappedFileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
     var view = f.CreateViewAccessor();
     // read/write to the view ...
 }
```

And in VBA (yea, I know...) I am opening this via calls to kernel32 functions, basically

```
hFileMap = OpenFileMapping(GENERIC_READ Or GENERIC_WRITE, 0, "TestMap")
hMM = MapViewOfFile(hFileMap, FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0)

Dim data(0 To 9) As Byte
' .. point data towards the hMM array data .. leaving out the code for brevity
```

My impression was that the data of both should be perfectly synchronized, i.e. when I'd e.g. set data(0) in vba to some byte value, it would be guaranteed to synchronize with the respective view in C#, e.g. view.ReadByte(0);  in C# afterwards (even if VERY shortly afterwards), it would be guaranteed to return the correct/updated value.

Is this assumption correct?
Or is there a lag in synchronization, meaning the array in process B (VBA) might not always be 100% synchronized with the view accessor in process A (C#) ? if there is, is there any inbuilt way to force and wait for synchronization?

Thanks

---

Asking as I'm facing an issue that would suggest my initial assumption is actually wrong. When I update the array in VBA and read it very very shortly afterwards in C#, it seems to still contain old data. When I introduce an artifical time delay, the data is back in line.

Just trying to make sure this is actually the cause of the issue, rather than somethign else being wrong here (some conceptual issue in the way I'm signaling or such)

---

For context, here is a bit of a drilldown of the approach I am trying:

I have two processes communicating with each other; the protocol is fairly clear, both processes will always know whose turn it is to send a message. So there is always a "reader" process who would just read data, and a "writer" process who pushes this data (the roles may switch, but it will always be clearly defined what process has what role).

My idea was to create a Memory Mapped File of length N, which could correspond to a layout of something like

```
enum IpcStatus : Byte
{
  // The reader can kepe reading, all fine
  Readable = 0,

  // MemoryMappedFileLayout.Data is full, and the writer wants to write some more data.
  // Once the reader has read the entire buffer, it must reset the file, i.e. set
  // MemoryMappedFileLayout.DataLength back to 0, and MemoryMappedFileLayout.Status back to 0.
  // The writer will keep polling this, and continues writing once Status is 0 again
  // and then begin reading from Data[0] onwards again
  BufferFull = 1,

  // The writer is currently updating MemoryMappedFileLayout.DataLength - so the reader
  // shouldn't read this value, but rather wait/spin until that's done
  LengthLocked = 2
}

struct MemoryMappedFileLayout
{
  // How many bytes of Data have actually been written / are meaningful?
  Int32 DataLength;
  IpcStatus Status;
  byte[N-sizeof(Int32)-sizeof(IpcStatus)] Data;
}
```

so let's say N = 10 (memory mapped file is 10 bytes long), meaning Data contains 5 bytes (10-sizeof(int32-sizeof(byte)).
Let's say memFile[0 To 9] is a byte array of length 10 representinv the memory of this.

Let's say the writer wants to write 7 bytes of data:

```
writer copies the first 5 bytes into memFile[5 to 9]
writer sets memFile[4] to IpcStatus.LengthLocked
writer sets memFile[0 To 3] to (Int32)5  // i.e. sets data length to 5
writer sets memFile[4] to IpcStatus.BufferFull  // i.e. signals to client that it needs to write more, but buffer full
writer keeps spinning and re-reading memFile[4] until it is == IpcStatus.Readable
writer copies last 2 bytes it needs to write into memFile[5 To 6]
writer sets memFile[4] To IpcStatus.LengthLocked
writer sets memFile[0 To 3] T0 (Int32)2
writer sets memFile[4] to IpcStatus.Readable
```

in parallel, the reader does the followings. Let's say the reader knows it will need to read exactly 7 bytes.

```
reader checks if memFile[4] is IpcStatus.LengthLocked; if so, spin and re-read until it is not anymore
reader reads memFile[0 To 3] -> first value it sees will be (Int32)5 // i.e. read length of available data, which is 5
reader reads memFile[5 To 9] and copies into its own output buffer
reader reads memFile[4] and sees its == IpcStatus.BufferFull at this point, so:
reader sets memFile[0 To 3] = 0 (e.g. data length = 0)
reader sets memFile[4] = IpcStatus.Readable
reader checks if memFile[4] is IpcStatus.LengthLocked; if so, spin and re-read until it is not anymore
reader reads memFile[0 To 3] -> it will now see (Int)2  // i.e. read length of available data, which is 2
reader reads memFile[5 To 6] and copies to its own output buffer
```

Comment: MMFs are very low-level interop objects.  You must always add the synchronization to ensure that the code in the second process cannot read the data before the first process has completed writing it.  Makes them quite hard to use correctly.  Consider the primitives that the OS built on top of them to make it easier.  Named pipes and local-loopback sockets.

Comment: Thanks. By "before the first process has completed writing it" - as in, has completed updating the byte array this maps to (I .. think .. I have ensured this), or is there some other sync that would need to be done?
I agree the other methods would be way easier; I have tried a TCP Conenction via localhost, but it took around 0.2ms to send some small data (30 bytes or such), struck me as very slow .. so was trying to explore alternative/faster routes

Comment: You'll have to show us how you ensure this, none is visible in the snippets and your question doesn't talk about it.  Speed up tcp by disabling nagle's algorithm.

Comment: @HansPassant are local-loopback sockets really built on top of memory mapped files?

Comment: Shared memory, the kernel can do that without explicitly creating an MMF.

Comment: @HansPassant I have updated the question with a bit of a drilldown of the approach I was/am trying

Comment: Looks like you are trying to read data between two processes.  In windows communications between processes are done by the Timer Tick Process which is updated using timers.  So two processes may not be synchronized and order then operating system runs the processes is not constant.  To prove the point if you added a timesptamp when the data is changes and when the 2nd process reads the data you will be able to determine what the root cause of the issue is.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks, that is unfortunate! I guess in that case it's never really practical to re-use / go back in the underlying array as it'd be extremely hard (impossible?) to synchronize without any more outside signals

Comment: You can use two bytes for each message.  One the data and 2nd a counter (0 - 255).  So you write the data and then increment counter.  Receive end only reads after is see a new count.

Comment: How would you handle large messages though? Say >100mb .. assuming buffer is smaller than that. You'd have to reset the memory in some synchronized way between both processes and start writing from the beginning again